# Show only API data with category_name : "WEBSITE" in Vue

Tags: vue.js, filter, axios, nuxt.js

I get my data from an API with :

```js
async mounted() {
  const { data } = await axios.get('/api/talent', {
    headers: {
      'X-AUTH-TOKEN': '####', 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  this.results = data.content
},
```

The API is like this :

```json
"talent_skills": [
  {
    "category_name": "Music",
    "name": "Pop",
    "level": 5
  },
  {
    "category_name": "Instruments",
    "name": "Guitar Accoustic",
    "level": 3
  },
  {
    "category_name": "WEBSITE",
    "name": "Guitar Electric",
    "level": 5
  },
  {
    "category_name": "WEBSITE",
    "name": "Roller Blading",
    "level": 3
  }
]
```

I want to show only the Talent_skills with the category_name : WEBSITE

Im trying to filter the axios result with :

```js
this.results = data.talent_skills.filter(data => data.category_name === 'WEBSITE')
```

But I got :

> Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

What is the good way or a link for learn how too filter the data by `category_name` ?

--EDIT--

```js
content: [{
  cache_is_website: true,
  firstname: '',
  fullname: '',
  fullname_sort: '',
  slug: '',
  talent_portfolios: [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: '',
      main: true,
      website: true,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: '',
      main: false,
      website: true,
    },
  ],
  talent_skills: [
    {
      category_name: 'Music',
      name: 'Pop',
      level: 5,
    },
    {
      category_name: 'Instruments',
      name: 'Guitar Accoustic',
      level: 3,
    },

    {
      category_name: 'WEBSITE',
      name: 'Singer',
      level: 5,
    },
    {
      category_name: 'WEBSITE',
      name: 'Guitar',
      level: 1,
    },
    {
      category_name: 'WEBSITE',
      name: 'Roller blading ',
      level: 1,
    },
  ],
}]
```

Comment: What do you have in `this.results` ? This is a good starting point: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Also, prefer not reusing the same variable name in your filter, aka `.filter(skill => skill.category_name === 'WEBSITE')` rather than using `data` again.

Comment: in this.results i got a lot of data from the API ... and im trying to enter the talent_skills array and get only the "category_name": "WEBSITE" ... Im trying with the filter that you teach me last time but im doing it wrongly

Comment: ok thank you Kissu i will change it

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us exactly what you do have in `this.results` at the point of your code?

Comment: I edit it and add what i got in result data.content

Comment: I’m so confused, because you’ve changed the example response about three times now. Can you show us what the API is _actually_ returning and let us know when you’ve decide yourself…?

Comment: He had some trouble copy pasting the actual payload, with a bit of guessing and formatting, it's okay. Can't blame him for having difficulties.

Comment: i remove some from the API response coz its too much lines maybe i cut wrongly ...excuse me when i EDIT ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to loop on your array but for the first item, you can use

```js
this.results = data.content[0].talent_skills.filter((skill) => skill.category_name === 'WEBSITE')
```

Comment: owow its working ..soo great thank you Kissu ... now i can finally filter by category_name ..last time you teach me how to do it by slug with image ...really thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're using `.filter` on undefined variable: "Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined".

The issue comes from the way you use the Axios response and not the function you give to the `.filter` method.

As mentionned in the Axios documentation, you can retrieve response data in the `data` property from the response:

> When using then, you will receive the response as follows:
>
> ```
> axios.get('/user/12345')
>     .then(function (response) {
>         console.log(response.data);
>         console.log(response.status);
>         console.log(response.statusText);
>         console.log(response.headers);
>         console.log(response.config);
>    });
> ```
>
> -- Axios documentation (from Github Axios project: https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema)

You need to use the following:

```js
const response = await axios.get(...);
this.results = response.data;
const talent_skills = this.results.talent_skills;

// OR
const { data } = await axios.get(...);
const talent_skills = data.talent_skills;
```

Comment: Thank you Paul ..i will read more the doc of Axios and about the 'const'

Comment: Since your edit, my answer is almost obsolete. The issue seemed to be about your use of Axios because you didn't tell about the `content` property in the data model returned from the API. The original question didn't tell about this array named `content`.